# How to update julia 0.4 without pain?

Tags: julia, updates, atom-editor

Recently, I want to update my current 0.4.X version to latest 0.5.0. What's the best practice to accomplish this job? 
Do I have to first remove my current version before installing the new one? 
What about these installed packages, do I have to reinstall them one by one? Can my IDE (like Atom) support the new version automatically (or only with slight modification)?

Answer (score 7):

Take the .julia/v0.4/REQUIRE file and plop it in .julia/v0.5, and then when you `Pkg.update()` it will add all of those packages. You might need to do `using Atom` in the REPL in order to have Juno properly re-compile before using it.

Comment: To add to Chris's answer, if you use IJulia/Jupter you also need to `Pkg.build("IJulia")` from the REPL with the latest version so that it will show up in Jupyter.

Comment: That should be automatic when IJulia is installed in the new version

Comment: Appologize for the delayed reply. Thank you chris, I followed your suggestion and copy the old REQUIRE file to .julia/v0.5. However, the `Pkg.update()` command seemed only clone a small fraction of the packages. For example, I have installed `Distributions IJulia DSGE Calendar RDatasets GLM DataFrames ZMQ PyPlot QuantEcon FastGaussQuadrature Gadfly Atom` but only the two of them are cloned

Comment: If you open up the require file are all of those listed?